# Can I provide free subdomain service of TLD .pro ?

Tags: top-level-domains

Can I provide free subdomain (second level) for free like `.co.cc` do?

I'm trying to register a `.pro` domain individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you'll have to have some sort of web interface where people can register it and manage their DNS records (your web server and DNS server have to work together).

If you actually want to host your domain here: http://freedns.afraid.org/ they have a feature where you can register your own subdomain on anyone else's domain (provided that the owner has their domain "open") and that if you have yours open, anyone else can register subdomains on your domain.

Or, you can manage the entire operation yourself if you get WHM/cPanel. You would provide the DNS functions only, not web hosting.

Comment: means I am able to provide .co.cc like service ??

Comment: @AryanG - See my comment to Nick below. Physically, yes. Legally? Ask a lawyer, but I think so.

Comment: Thanks for help, I want to start a small 3rd level free domain service. which domain you prefer? I think it is risky to choose `.pro`

Comment: @AryanG - I personally would go with a 2-letter suffix. Contact me, (click username, homepage, contact page) and I'll send you some more info of what domains I'd use, and more help in actually setting it up.

Answer (score 3):

The official [.pro end user terms of use](http://www.registry.pro/legal/user-terms) includes the following statement:

> "You shall not, shall not agree to, and shall not authorize or
>   encourage any third party to: ... (f) facilitate use of the Service by any
>   person or entity not a party to this Agreement."

This clause might be open to interpretation, but it suggests that you can't provide free or paid subdomains of a .pro domain without breaking the terms of use.

Comment: Free subdomains could be "a way of advertising" and "bound by our own Agreement that they are part of our Party." By purchasing the domain, `The Service is made available to you for your professional use only. As such, you agree that you are a person or entity who provides professional services and has been admitted to or licensed by,`

Comment: @ionFish No provision is made for advertising in the terms, the opening clause states "Nothing in this Agreement shall be deemed to confer any third party rights or benefits", and the domain is intended for professional bodies only. It seems fairly clear that subletting (even for free) to anyone who wants a subdomain is outside the intended use. The right thing to do would be to contact registry.pro and ask them for an official position, but the current terms appear to lean against free .pro subdomains for all.

Comment: @Nick: very interesting point, but I think they can't do this. Once I bought a domain, such domain is mine and someone can not force me not to create a millions of subdomains. Any subdomains would still end with `mydomain.pro` thus as long as `I'm a person or entity who provides professional service` i should be fine.